# Xcode / IOS Code visibility

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, security, encryption

How easy can it be for people to see the code / inner working mechanics of a published iOS app? 
E.g if there was a certain algorithm or function/class, how easily could people be able to read that?

If it’s possible, is there any way to camouflage or encrypt it so the code can’t be read? 
Cheers

Answer (score -2):

A certain algorithm or function/class is not going to be visible to anyone just from having access to a published app.  The apps executable has been compiled and optimised so the original source does not even exist inside it.  The executables are also encrypted and while can be decrypted if you jail brake a device even then you won't get much info.

While a lot of information about how an app works can be deduced by examining how it works individual algorithms is not something to worry about.

Plus what makes you think anyone is even going to bother trying for your app.

**EDIT**

As there was some confusion here is a link which talks about the binaries being encrypted when producing universal and thinned ipa files:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014195-CH1-APP_STORE_CONSIDERATIONS

Comment: I've never heard of a compiled program being encrypted for standard use without some sort of external force such as full drive encryption or home folder encryption etc. Could you link a source for compilers that encrypt their code please?

Comment: I never said the compiler did any encryption.  The executable itself is encrypted on the file system.

Comment: Ahh right. Thank you - I appear to have misunderstood :)

Comment: No problem.  Of course the IPA itself is not encrypted just the actual executable upon delivery to the device.  So potentially someone could get access to the assets but not review the code.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down vote.  I don't really care I'm just interested what is wrong.